# Delphi TidHttp Logon Post Not Working?

Tags: delphi, idhttp

I am trying to logon to a website which has the following authorization coding shown below.  My application is a RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo FireMonkey application with `TIdHTTP`, `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` and `TWebBrowser` components.

I return the response from the post into the `TWebBrowser`, but I am just getting the logon page back from the post.  The site I am trying to logon to is: https://admin.salestaxonline.com/default_sto.aspx

I am using the correct username and password.  Why does it not appear that I am logging on?

Here are the pertinent entries from the logon page:

```
div id="pnlLogin" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'cmdLogin2')"
input name="UN" type="text" id="UN" class="form-control"
input name="PW" type="password" id="PW" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"
input type="submit" name="cmdLogin2" value="Login" id="cmdLogin2" class="btn btn-md btn-default btn-block"
```

Here is the code (corrected to show all pertinent lines):

```
procedure LoginToSite(AUrl,AUsername,APassword: String);
var
  Request: TStringList;
  ResponseText: String;
begin
  try
    Request := TStringList.Create;
    try
        ResponseText := IdHttp.Get(AUrl);
        Request.Add('UN='+AUsername);
        Request.Add('PW='+APassword);
        Request.Add('CmdLogin2=Login');
        IdHttp.Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';
        IdHttp.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
        IdHttp.AllowCookies := True;
        IdHttp.HandleRedirects := True;
        ResponseText := IdHttp.Post(AUrl,Request);
        WB.LoadFromStrings(ResponseText,'http://www.google.com');
      finally
        Request.Free;
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        LogMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  end;
```

I used Fidder to access the post request from the browser:

```
ScriptManager1  UpdatePanel1|cmdLogin2
__EVENTTARGET   
__EVENTARGUMENT 
__VIEWSTATE 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
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR    3D83CE1D
__EVENTVALIDATION   /wEdAAalocif5oqNVmBq4XHuTUlFZXMJTqauloOO7cRYBXw1wxoYRGJFkVe8AgQLV57tKfJb7LxF45ueUaenG3mYhJt9tc7YpkYcYhE3nrt/HTbMZbqic3S0ZDjCzqE9M2ZhdeTMjwr1n8f6NXCOvmYjlNIvvg2IKZmfevDvrXmf2JYyLw==
UN  ....Hidden....
PW  ....Hidden....
__ASYNCPOST true
cmdLogin2   Login
```

Comment: Cookies! Did I mention cookies?

Comment: I suggest you login to the site with a real web browser and capture its HTTP traffic, then capture `TIdHTTP`'s HTTP traffic, and compare them for differences. You will likely find that you are not sending everything that a web browser would send

Comment: @whosrdaddy: that is a good point.  That is a common culprit. You should `Get` the login page first so `TIdHTTP` can cache any cookies, and then `Post` the login so `TIdHTTP` can send back any cookies it needs